# How and why an edit is counted?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, edits

To day I edited a post and fixed a spelling mistake [image], [Edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147481/loading-3d-model-in-cocos3d) but this edit doen't show in my editing history, [image]. Thus my questions are:

- Why it's not showing in my edit history?
- And/Or how an edit is counted as an valid(I know how is it valuable) edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It *is* in [your edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656600/rptwsthi?tab=activity&sort=revisions).
- You need a minimum of 5 edits in a certain time frame in order to show up in the editors list for that period. This has been your only edit since Sunday, so that's 1 edit this week, therefore you won't show up in the editors tab for this week until you edit more posts.

  You already have more than 2000 reputation on Stack Overflow, so you have [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). Any edits you submit will be committed immediately and count for the purposes of editing badges and the users/editors tab.

Comment: Thanks for resolving curiosity. And editing my post (removing that bug tag) :)