# Editors in SE editor page

Tags: discussion

At the MSE Editor page, 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors

1. What is the minimum reputation requirement to become an editor ?
2. Does this list of editors change or is it static ?
3. Who has the privilege to make a user editor ? (Mods ?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of edits are counted in /users?tab=editors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/what-kind-of-edits-are-counted-in-userstab-editors)

Comment: @gnat I don't think that is duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the minimum reputation requirement to become an editor?

Once you make 5 edits of non-yours posts (if you have <2k only approved edits count, obviously :)), your name would appear in the list for corresponding periods (week, month, quarter, year)

> Does this list of editors change or is it static?

It is dynamic, cached lil bit. Once a user which appears in this list makes an edit, number of edits made by him and shown in this list, increments. (Also the same number appears in "impact">"posts edited" in your profile)

> Who has the privilege to make a user editor?

Already answered; see the first paragraph.

Comment: caching... really? It will be all wrong

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Peter answer. The list is indeed dynamic, but seem to only include users that have performed at least 5 edits in the specified timeframe.

I am basing this assumption on [this meta post by Bolt.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166467/171199)

> You need a minimum of 5 edits in a certain time frame in order to show up in the editors list for that period. This has been your only edit since Sunday, so that's 1 edit this week, therefore you won't show up in the editors tab for this week until you edit more posts.

This seem to be confirmed by the fact that if you order the list, no user with lesser than 5 edits is shown.

No other requirements should be present: multiple low rep users are in the list, so you do not seem to require specific privileges. For reference "user2060383" currently has about 150rep points and is in the list.

Comment: Also confirmed by hovering over the tab name.

Comment: @Woodface so true, but I tried to find another reference for sake of completion (hope they buy it, actually I didn't notice before)

Comment: [Here's a post by an SE developer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237367/259867)

Answer (score 0):

That list is dynamic and shows the total edits done by a user over the time period shown as long as there are more than five for the period. You can suggest an edit with a reputation of one and once those are approved you can appear on the list. When you have less than 2k reputation you will get +2 up to a limit of 1000 for each suggested edit that is accepted.

But technically you could lose that reputation through other means such as downvotes and appear on the list with a reputation of one.

On the [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page you can see at 2k reputation edits to any question or answer are applied immediately, so in practice most people who appear on the list will have above 2k reputation because they can do minor edits that may be rejected if they had to go through the suggested edits queue. Plus they will generally be more familiar with the system and know what edits and retagging is appropriate.

Also to clarify when you suggest an edit it goes into a queue and is approved (or rejected) by 2-3 users depending on the site with a 2k reputation that have already earnt the privilege to edit directly without approval.

Comment: Your answer seems to have lots of excess info...